# Is $G/ \gamma_n(G)$ nilpotent for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Looking at the lower central series of a group $G$, I noticed that $G/\gamma_2(G)=G/G'$ is nilpotent (it's abelian). I was wondering if this property holds for any quotient $G/ \gamma_n(G)$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I tried to prove it by induction.

If $n=1,2$ it's obvious. Let $n > 2$ and suppose that  $G/ \gamma_n(G)$ is nilpotent. We know that a group $X$ is nilpotent if and only if there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $\gamma_{k+1}(X)=1$. So in our case there exists a $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $\gamma_{k+1}(G/ \gamma_n(G))=1$ and this happens if and only if $\gamma_{k+1}(G) \leq \gamma_n(G)$.

Now let's consider $G/ \gamma_{n+1}(G)$.
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
\gamma_{k+2}\left(\frac{G}{ \gamma_{n+1}(G)}\right) &= \Big[\frac{G}{ \gamma_{n+1}(G)}, \gamma_{k+1}\left(\frac{G} {\gamma_{n+1}(G)}\right)\Big] \\
& = \Big[\frac{G}{ \gamma_{n+1}(G)}, \frac{\gamma_{k+1}(G)\gamma_{n+1}(G)}{\gamma_{n+1}(G)} \Big] \\
&= \frac{[G, \gamma_{k+1}(G)\gamma_{n+1}(G)]\gamma_{n+1}(G)}{\gamma_{n+1}(G)} \\
& \leq \frac{[G, \gamma_n(G)\gamma_{n+1}(G)]\gamma_{n+1}(G)}{\gamma_{n+1}(G)} \\
& = \frac{[G, \gamma_{n}(G)]\gamma_{n+1}(G)}{\gamma_{n+1}(G)} \\
&= \frac{\gamma_{n+1}(G)}{\gamma_{n+1}(G)} \\
&= \{1\}
\end{split}
\end{align*}
So $G/ \gamma_{n+1}(G)$ is nilpotent.

Is this idea correct? Thanks for your hints.

Comment: This follows from the fact that the lower central series is a central series.

Comment: So is there a faster way than induction to see the result?

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct, though some of the calculations might need some justification beyond just symbol manipulation.

A slightly more conceptual argument generalizes the well known result:

> Let $G$ be a group. Then $[G,G]$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/[G,G]$ is abelian. If $f\colon G\to A$ is a group homomorphism, and $A$ is abelian, then $[G,G]\leq \ker(f)$.

Namely, we have:

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be a group, and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\gamma_n(G)$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/\gamma_n(G)$ is nilpotent of class at most $n$. If $f\colon G\to K$ is a group homomorphism, and $K$ is nilpotent of class at most $n$, then $\gamma_n(G)\leq \ker(f)$.

A useful thing here is that the subgroup $\gamma_n(G)$ are *verbal subgroups*; as a consequence, we have:

> **Lemma.** Let $f\colon G\to K$ be a group homomorphism. Then for every $n$, $f(\gamma_n(G))\leq \gamma_n(K)$. If $f$ is surjective, then $f(\gamma_n(G))=\gamma_n(K)$.

*Proof of Lemma.* First we prove the inclusion. We proceed by induction on $n$. The result is clear for $\gamma_1(G)=G$ and $\gamma_1(K)=K$.

For $n=2$, $\gamma_2(G)$ is generated by elements of the form $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$; then $f([x,y]) = [f(x),f(y)]\in [K,K]=\gamma_2(K)$, so $f(\gamma_2(G))\leq \gamma_2(K)$.

Assume that $f(\gamma_r(G))\leq\gamma_r(K)$. Looking at the elements of the form $[u,g]$, with $u\in\gamma_r(G)$, which generate $\gamma_{r+1}(G)$, we have $f(u)\in\gamma_r(K)$ by the induction hypothesis, so $f([u,g]) = [f(u),f(g)]\in [\gamma_r(K),K] = \gamma_{r+1}(K)$. Thus, $f(\gamma_{r+1}(G))\leq \gamma_{r+1}(K)$, as desired.

To prove equality when $f$ is surjective, we again proceed by induction. The result is clear for $n=1$. Consider an arbitrary generator of $\gamma_2(K)$, which has the form $[k_1,k_2]$. By surjectivity, we can find $g_1,g_2\in G$ with $f(g_i)=k_i$. Then $f([g_1,g_2]) = [f(g_1),f(g_2)] = [k_1,k_2]\in f(\gamma_2(G))$. Thus, $\gamma_2(K)\leq f(\gamma_2(G))$, giving equality.

Assuming that $f(\gamma_r(G))=\gamma_r(K)$, let $[u,k]$ be an arbitrary generator of $\gamma_{r+1}(K)$, with $u\in\gamma_r(K)$ and $k\in K$. By the induction hypothesis there exists $x\in \gamma_r(G)$ such that $f(x)=u$, and by surjectivity of $f$ there exists $g\in G$ with $f(g)=k$. Then $[x,g]\in[\gamma_r(G),G] = \gamma_{r+1}(G)$, and $f([x,g]) = [f(x),f(g)] = [u,k]$. Thus, $\gamma_{r+1}(K)\leq f(\gamma_{r+1}(G))$, giving equality. $\Box$

Now we can prove the Theorem:

*Proof of Theorem.* First, we show that $G/\gamma_n(G)$ is nilpotent of class  at most $n$. Consider the surjective homomorphism $\pi\colon G\to G/\gamma_n(G)$. By the Lemma, we have that $\gamma_n(G/\gamma_n(G)) = \pi(\gamma_n(G))$. But $\pi(\gamma_n(G))=\gamma_n(G)/\gamma_n(G)$ is the trivial subgroup of $G/\gamma_n(G)$, so $\gamma_n(G/\gamma_n(G))=\{1\}$. Thus, $G/\gamma_n(G)$ is nilpotent of class at most $n$.

Now assume that $f\colon G\to K$ is a group homomorphism, with $K$ nilpotent of class at most $n$. Then $f(\gamma_n(G))\leq \gamma_n(K)=\{1_K\}$, so $\gamma_n(G)\leq \ker(f)$, as required.

Finally, let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is nilpotent of class at most $n$. Then $\pi\colon G\to G/N$ has $\gamma_n(G)\leq \ker(\pi)=N$. Thus, $\gamma_n(G)$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that the quotient is nilpotent of class at most $n$, as desired. $\Box$

I will note that we also obtain the corollary:

> **Corollary.** Let $G$ be a group, and let $1\leq k\leq n$ be positive integers. Then $\gamma_k(G)/\gamma_n(G) = \gamma_k(G/\gamma_n(G))$.

*Proof.* Applying the Lemma to the surjective group homomorphism $\pi\colon G\to G/\gamma_n(G)$, we obtain that $\pi(\gamma_k(G)) = \gamma_k(G/\gamma_n(G))$, which gives the desired equality. $\Box$